# How to get connect Azure SQL instance using service principal with federated credentials in C#

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, azure-service-principal

I used below working code to connect Azure SQL instance using my service principal which has a secret. The code shown here is working fine. But I am confused how to get `AccessToken` (`conn.AccessToken`) using the `ServicePrincipal` without a secret or certificate.

```
string clientSecretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
string sqlConnectionString = string.Format("Data Source=tcp:{0},1433;Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=False;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False", configs.SqlServerName, configs.SqlDatabaseName);

string AadInstance = "https://login.windows.net/{0}";

AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(AadInstance, configs.PMETenantID));

ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(configs.AppClientID, clientSecretKey);

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(configs.SqlResourceId, clientCredential).Result;

List<Employee> employeeResult = new();

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
{
    conn.AccessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    conn.Open();

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sampleSqlQuery, conn))
    {
        var results = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (results.Read())
        {
            employeeResult.Add(new Employee
            {
                EmployeeId = results.GetInt16(0),
                FirstName = results.GetString(1),
                LastName = results.GetString(2),
                LastUpdatedDate = results.GetDateTime(3),
                SessionId = results.GetGuid(4)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone give me sample method to connect to an Azure SQL instance using my service principal with federated credentials? Meaning, my service principal does not have a secret or a certificate associated with it. It has a managed identity associated with it.

Comment: Could you please confirm whether token generated with managed identity works for your requirement?

Comment: Yes. Using powershell commands inside Azure Runbook, I am able to connect to Azure Sql Instance and get data from table.

$null = Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId $ManagedIdentity).context
$resourceUri = "https://database.windows.net/"  # For Azure SQL Database

    # Get the access token using Azure.Identity module
    $tokenCredential = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl $resourceUri).Token

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using below code

```html
var aADManagedIdentity = configs.Tenants.Where(x => x.Description.Equals("PME")).First();
var aadAuthContext = new AadAuthContext(aADManagedIdentity.Auth.ManagedIdentityClientId, aADManagedIdentity.Id, aADManagedIdentity.Auth.AadInstance);
aadAuthContext.AadAppClientId = aADManagedIdentity.Auth.ClientId;
var token = Authentication.GetTokenUsingSpnAsync(new string[] { configs.SqlResourceId + "/.default" }
    , aadAuthContext, logger).Result.AccessToken;
```